# GitLabへssh接続確認を行うと「Permission denied (publickey).」

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

#### 発生している問題

以前、接続してpushできていたはずのGitlabのリポジトリにsshで接続しようとするとエラーになってしまう。

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ ssh -T git@gitlab.com
Permission denied (publickey).
```

#### 解決のために行ってみたこと

https://qiita.com/redamoon/items/07e445d1fce360cb5fa3
↑こちらの記事を参考に公開鍵と秘密鍵を再度作成

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ ssh-keygen -C "ログイン時のアドレス@fuga.com" -t rsa
```

~/.ssh/configを以下のように編集

```
Host gitlab  
    HostName gitlab
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

公開鍵（id_rsa_pub）を表示させ「ssh-rsa ~ メールアドレスの直前」までをコピーしGitlabのSSH Keysの設定で新規追加

接続確認を行うと最初のエラーとなる

```
[vagrant@localhost .ssh]$ ssh -T git@gitlab.com
Permission denied (publickey).
```

上記で作成した公開鍵、秘密鍵は以前同じ名前で作成した鍵が存在したので

```
/home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa already exists.
Overwrite (y/n)? y
```

↑こちらで上書きして作り直したものになります。

このエラーの原因や解決の手口の検討がつかず、お手上げ状態です、、、
原因と解決策をご教示いただけると大変助かります。何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/195995

Answer (score 1):

リモートリポジトリがGitLabのSaasではないものを利用していたのに気づかずgit@gitlab.comに接続しようとしていました、、、
正しいURLで接続確認を行ったところ問題なく接続できました。